# Do user (group) ID mappings in `/proc/[pid]/uid_map` (`/proc/[pid]/gid_map`) only apply for the process `[pid]` or globally for the whole namespace?

Tags: debian, kernel, namespace

After reading `man user_namespaces`, I'm not sure, whether user (group) ID mappings to the parent namespace, set in `/proc/[pid]/uid_map` (`/proc/[pid]/gid_map`), apply to all processes in the namespace or only for the process `[pid]`?

If the mappings apply to all processes, then it's a bit of a race-condition, which process writes to one of the above files first, since they can only be written once.

If the mappings only apply for the processes `[pid]`, then I find it weird that UID `0` may be mapped to different user IDs in the parent namespaces.

Can someone explain?

`man user_namespaces`:

```
... 
User and group ID mappings: uid_map and gid_map
       When a user namespace is created, it starts out without a mapping of user IDs (group IDs) to the parent user namespace.  The /proc/[pid]/uid_map and  /proc/[pid]/gid_map  files  (available  since
       Linux  3.5)  expose  the  mappings for user and group IDs inside the user namespace for the process pid.  These files can be read to view the mappings in a user namespace and written to (once) to
       define the mappings.
...
```

Comment: I'm disappointed (but not surprised) to see this question down-voted with no comments. The tooltips for the down and up arrows state: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" This question starts with "After reading `man user_namespaces`". I feel that the SO community is becoming ~~p~~**re**gressively *elite/bro* in culture. Either that or people are using the down-vote to indicate "I don't know the answer". Both are regrettable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manpage says

> After the creation of a new user namespace, the `uid_map` file of *one*
>          of the processes in the namespace may be written to *once* to define
>          the mapping of user IDs in the new user namespace.  An attempt to
>          write more than once to a `uid_map` file in a user namespace fails with
>          the error `EPERM`.  Similar rules apply for `gid_map` files.

It takes some measure of reading between the lines, but this is consistent with the fact that all processes in a user namespace share the same user and group mappings.

This does mean there’s a bit of a race, but the privilege requirements mean that if a hostile process is privileged enough to hijack your user namespace, you’ve lost anyway. The race can be mitigated for all intents and purposes by handling `EPERM` in the process which expects to set the mappings up in a new user namespace: start over in a new user namespace.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. I read the sentence "*After the creation of a new user namespace, the **uid_map** file of one of the processes in the namespace may be written to once*" as: each process may write to its **uid_map** file once. From your answer, I understand that *once* applies to the whole sentence before, correct?

Comment: That’s right, the mapping can only be written once, for the whole user namespace.